# Do periodic solutions of this system always exist?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, periodic-functions

Consider the following system of autonomous differential equations on $\mathbb{R}$:

$$\frac{d}{dt}x(t)=f(x(t),y(t)) \ \ \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ \ \frac{d}{dt}y(t)=g(x(t),y(t)) \ \ \ \ (1)$$
where $f$ and $g$ satisfy local Lipschitz condition on both $x$ and $y$.

While I was plotting some graphs modeling some ecological models, such as models of the interaction between populations of predators and preys, I noticed that this type of systems **always have a periodic solution**, provided it has a global bounded solution. Usually this periodic solution is a steady state (a constant solution).

Is there any theorem which states this result? That is, is this theroem correct:

**Theorem.** If $f$ and $g$ are locally Lipschitz with respect to both variables and if $(1)$ has a bounded solution on $t\in[0,\infty)$, then $(1)$  has a periodic solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is a bounded solution, its $\omega$-limit set is compact.  Now use the [Poincaré–Bendixson theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9%E2%80%93Bendixson_theorem).